# Remove Calendar from Outlook 2013

Tags: calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013

I use Outlook 2013 / Office 365 and shortly after installing I made the mistake to add two calendars:

- A "ics" calendar hosted on the web (Formula 1 race dates from formel1.de)
- Another calendar where I tried to use WEBDAV to share my calendar.

It all didn't work out as expected - so now I try to remove those calendars again... and again... and again... and again...

They keep coming back every time I restart Outlook.

It does not matter which of these I do:

- Remove them from the calendar view
- Remove them from "Internet Calendars" and "Published Calendars" in Account settings

And they are not just returning once, they multiply. When I remove them in the account settings, I end up with two copies in my calendar view.

I could live with them just "lingering around", but I get error messages every time outlook tries to sync those "Internet Calendars".

Help?

Where does Outlook store the information about those calendars? Where do I need to get my fingers dirty to remove those references manually?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this from memory, I'll double check all the steps in about 10 - 12 hours and edit my answer if required, but I think this is how to do it. Down at the bottom left hand side of Outlook it says: "mail - calendar - people - tasks - ..." click the ... and go to "folders" there you should see the folder structure that includes the duplicate calendar files. You should be able to right click and delete, or move the calendars to different locations.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I think I never tried to click that thing so far - but sadly it does not (yet) solve my problem. I deleted the calendars from there and restartet Outlook - just to see the deleted entries return. I'm sure: Outlook is trying to drive me crazy!

Comment: are you synced to Exchange using an Exchange account? When I get back to my work computer in the morning I will poke around and figure out what is going on. I just had this happen as well, but I added 5 calendars and was able to get rid of them all. Keep the faith I'll be back in touch.

Comment: At this moment I'm connected to 5 IMAP mail accounts, 6 POP3 mail accounts and one free "Outlook.com / Exchange Active Sync" account (used for the shared calendar functionality - but that's not the calendar I want to remove). But nothing like a "company Exchange server".

Comment: The calendar may have been communicated back to the exchange server (or possibly one of the IMAP servers). If so you'll want to verify that Outlook syncs the deletion information back to the exchange server (or IMAP server) before restarting Outlook. Down at the bottom there's usually a status that says something like "connected to outlook" when changes are made the status changes: "syncing <current folder> with <server>". Wait for the status to say "all folders up to date", then restart Outlook. Hitting F9 should also synchronize all folders, and should give you a pop-up status dialog box.

Comment: If that fails, log in directly to all the web apps for the IMAP and Outlook.com account(s) to see if the calendars are there. You may need to delete from multiple locations.

Comment: As far as I can tell the calendars are not coming from any of the servers. In the folder view they appear in their own PST-File (german "Internetkalender", which probably translates to "Internet Calendar" in English locales). The problem MIGHT be connected to the fact that the WEBDAV server I used for the attempted "shared" calendar does not exist anymore and that Outlook cannot update it anymore. But there is no way to bring that back easily.

Comment: when you delete the calendar from your folder view does the status at the bottom change?

Comment: Nope. Everything remains as it is.

Comment: you could try disconnecting one by one the email accounts, after each is disconnected, delete the calendar, shut down then restart outlook. That will tell you if it's grabbing the calendar from one of the mail servers...or, disconnect all of them - delete the calendar (if it stays deleted it's one of the servers) then 1 by one add them back to Outlook. if it's not coming from a server, you might have a bad pst file. MS has an onboard tool for checking the pst...